# Can not generate createsamples and traincascade executables

Tags: opencv, cmake

I'm trying to build OpenCV from source code, using latest editions of MS Visual Studio 2019 and CMake 3.15.3.

As shown in the snapshot attached, not all executable files had been generated, mainly `createsamples` and `traincascade`

[image: sa]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

was removed after OpenCV 3.4 because of legacy C-API removal:

https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/13231

So it looks like you should use OpenCV 3.4 for training cascade classifiers.

Answer (score 0):

These apps are considered obsolete in the latest OpenCV, given the removal of the legacy C API. See this [issue](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/13231) on Github. If you really want to try to include them in your build you can try these steps:

In your `source/apps` folder, the `CMakeLists.txt` file, seen [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/apps/CMakeLists.txt) in Github, needs to be modified. Specifically, the `traincascade` and `createsamples` directories are not added, but are commented out at the end of the file:

```
#ocv_add_app(traincascade)   # <--- Uncomment these two lines
#ocv_add_app(createsamples)  # <--- 
ocv_add_app(annotation)
ocv_add_app(visualisation)
ocv_add_app(interactive-calibration)
ocv_add_app(version)
```

If you uncomment these lines, the respective directories will be traversed in CMake and the projects will be included.